# Get Sibling Node using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an XML string as below

```
<Message>
  <Result>A</Result>
  <Note>AA</Note>
  <Note>AAA</Note>
  <Note>AAAA</Note>
  <Result>B</Result>
  <Note>BB</Note>
  <Note>BBB</Note>
  <Note>BBB</Note>
</Message>
```

I want to select the immediate 3 `Note` nodes of each `Result` Node using SQL and append them to each other. How I do that?

```
For Result A -> AA+AAA+AAAA
For Result B -> BB+BBB+BBBB
```

Comment: Without the RDBMS you're using (SQL Server, MySQL etc) this is impossible to answer... XML querying is different across most vendors. What RDBMS are you using and have you made an attempt yourself?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What problem are you having?

Comment: @podiluska -I don't know how to get the immediate nodes using sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have an XML that looks like this:

```xml
<Item Result="A">
  <Note>AA</Note>
  <Note>AAA</Note>
  <Note>AAAA</Note>
</Item>
<Item Result="B">
  <Note>BB</Note>
  <Note>BBB</Note>
  <Note>BBB</Note>
</Item>
```

Then it would be easy to generate the result you want by shredding on `Item` and using `for xml path('')` to concatenate the `Note` nodes.

```sql
select T.X.value('@Result', 'nvarchar(100)') as Result,
       (
       select T2.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')+' '
       from T.X.nodes('Note') T2(X)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Note
from @XML.nodes('/Item') as T(X);
```

You can rebuild your XML into the desired format using this query.

```sql
set @XML =  @XML.query('for $n in /Message/Result
                        return element Item {
                                            attribute Result{$n/text()},
                                            /Message/Note[. >> $n][position() < 4]
                                            }');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19494)

Another option is to shred on `Message/*` and enumerate all rows using `row_number()` in a CTE. Use the CTE in the main query and in the sub-query that uses `for xml path('')` to concatenate the strings with a join that uses the generated numbers.

```sql
with C as 
(
  select T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value,
         T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
         row_number() over(order by T.X)as  rn
  from @XML.nodes('/Message/*') as T(X)
)
select C1.Value as Result,
       (
       select C2.Value+' '
       from C as C2
       where C2.rn > C1.rn and
             C2.rn < C1.rn + 4
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Note
from C as C1
where C1.NodeName = 'Result'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19495)

<sub>Note: The technique using `row_number()` to enumerate nodes in a XML document relies on knowledge of the internal implementation of how SQL Server parses XML. The behaviour is not documented by Microsoft. Adam Machanic has blogged about it here: [Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/03/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense-rank.aspx)</sub>